# Android Creating and using methods

Tags: android, android-activity, methods, device

I'm trying to make an application. I have a few problems.
I want to create device information in "DeviceActivity.java" file and use it on any page.

The code block I created on MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String email;
int MY_PERMISSIONS_EMAIL = 8889;

String imei;
int MY_PERMISSIONS_IMEI = 8889;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ////////////////////// E-Posta Sorgulama //////////////////////
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_EMAIL);
    } else {
        Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this).getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                email = account.name;
            }
        }

    }
    TextView epota = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    epota.setText("E-posta: " + email);
    ////////////////////// E-Posta Sorgulama Son //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// Cihaz Modeli Sorgulama //////////////////////
    String CihazModel = Build.MODEL;
    TextView cihazmodel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cihaz_model);
    cihazmodel.setText("Cihaz Modeli: " + CihazModel);
    ////////////////////// Cihaz Modeli Sorgulama Son //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// Cihaz İsmi Sorgulama //////////////////////
    String CihazIsim = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    TextView cihazisim = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cihaz_isim);
    cihazisim.setText("Cihaz İsmi: " + CihazIsim.toUpperCase()+ " " + CihazModel);
    ////////////////////// Cihaz İsmi Sorgulama Son //////////////////////


    ////////////////////// Bellek Sorgulama //////////////////////
    RandomAccessFile reader = null;
    String load = null;
    DecimalFormat twoDecimalForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double totRam = 0;
    String lastValue = "";
    try {
        reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
        load = reader.readLine();

        // Get the Number value from the string
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(load);
        String value = "";
        while (m.find()) {
            value = m.group(1);
            // System.out.println("Ram : " + value);
        }
        reader.close();

        totRam = Double.parseDouble(value);
        // totRam = totRam / 1024;

        double mb = totRam / 1024.0;
        double gb = totRam / 1048576.0;
        double tb = totRam / 1073741824.0;

        if (tb > 1) {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(tb).concat(" TB");
        } else if (gb > 1) {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(gb).concat(" GB");
        } else if (mb > 1) {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(mb).concat(" MB");
        } else {
            lastValue = twoDecimalForm.format(totRam).concat(" KB");
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Streams.close(reader);
    }


    String CihazBellek = lastValue;
    TextView cihazbellek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cihaz_bellek);
    cihazbellek.setText("Cihaz Bellek: " + CihazBellek);
    ////////////////////// Bellek Sorgulama Son //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// İşletim Sistemi //////////////////////
    String CihazOs = "Android";
    TextView cihazos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cihaz_os);
    cihazos.setText("Cihaz OS: " + CihazOs);
    ////////////////////// İşletim Sistemi Son //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// Cihaz ID Sorgulama //////////////////////
    String CihazId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    TextView cihazid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cihaz_id);
    cihazid.setText("Cihaz ID: " + CihazId);
    ////////////////////// Cihaz ID Sorgulama Son //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// Cihaz OS Versiyonu Sorgulama //////////////////////
    Integer CihazApi = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    TextView cihazapi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cihaz_api);
    cihazapi.setText("Cihaz Api: " + CihazApi.toString());
    ////////////////////// Cihaz OS Versiyonu Sorgulama Son //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// Cihaz Zaman Dilimi Sorgulama //////////////////////
    String TimeZone = java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    TextView timezone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timezone);
    timezone.setText("Timezone: " + TimeZone);
    ////////////////////// Cihaz Zaman Dilimi Sorgulama Son //////////////////////

    ////////////////////// Cihaz IMEI Sorgulama //////////////////////
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_IMEI);
    } else {
        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei = tManager.getDeviceId();

    }

    TextView cihazimei = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imei);
    cihazimei.setText("Cihaz Imei: " + imei);
    ////////////////////// Cihaz IMEI Sorgulama Son //////////////////////
}
}
```

I want to adapt the codes on this page to "DeviceActivity.java" page and use it on other pages.

Comment: and what is a problem? Why you can't adapt it? Or you just want somebody to do it instead of you?

Comment: It works when I add it to the homepage but I can not run it on another page. I did not want anyone else to do it, I asked for help. @VladMatvienko

Comment: why you can't run it from another page? what is a problem there? Which kind of help you want?

Comment: I want to know where I made mistakes. @VladMatvienko

Comment: why you think you made mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just create a new public java class and add those code there. Then call the method from the class on the page required.

```
public class DeviceActivity { 
public DeviceActivity(Context context) {this.context = context;} 
public YourMethod(int someVariable, string someOtherVariable) { 
// Your code here. 
} 
}
```

Then call it as follows:

```
DeviceActivity deviceActivity = new DeviceActivity(YourActivity.this);
deviceActivity.YourMethod(someVariable, someOtherVariable);
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

Based on what I understand from you, try the following. I am unsure what errors you are experiencing, but I cannot seem to understand the issue clearly. Follow below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseActivity db = new DatabaseActivity();
        db.SaveInformationToDatabase(variable, otherVariable); //Add your own variables.
    }
}

public class DatabaseActivity {
    public void SaveInformationToDatabase(int variable, string otherVariable) {
        //Add your code to save details to database.
    }

    public Request retrieveDetailsFromDatabase() {
        //Add your code to retrieve the details from database as Json
    }
}

public class DeviceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DatabaseActivity db = new DatabaseActivity();
        Request request = db.retrieveDetailsFromDatabase();

        //Use request to retrieve Json and set details retrieved.
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? According to what I understood, you want that code to be called by ANY Activity without you having to rewrite the code in every Activity class?

Comment: I am trying to create 3 pages.
1- MainActivity.java: Sends the user information to the automatic database when the page is opened.
2- DatabaseActivity.java: The page that sends information to the database.
3- DeviceActivity.java: Finds the device information and shows it on the DatabaseActivity.java page.

Comment: Try this - to the public java class, add 2 methods, one that saves the details to the database and one to retrieve the details. On MainActivity.java call the save function and on the DatabaseActivity.java call the retrieve function. If you are still struggling I will post codes as soon as I am able, since I am not at my computer.  But I assume that you have codes to save and retrieve from database.

Comment: The database connection is running.

https://postimg.org/image/jh39luyip

https://postimg.org/image/b08cooj7l

Comment: See updated answer. Hopefully this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But my problem is not the database. I can send new information to the database. My problem is finding the device information on page1 and displaying this information on page2. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: If you only want the specific device information to be displayed on the second page, why not retrieve it from there? Is there a reason it has to be retrieved from page 1? Call the functions that you use on page 1 on page 2.